# iOS - Core Data - Saving an object that contains an array of Objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm just getting started with Core data, (and I'm also trying to use Magical Record). I'm creating a pretty simple Payment tracking app.

I would like to save a Payment object that has an array of Debtors. This is what my Payment object looks like

```
@class Debtor;

@interface Payment : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *paymentAmountString;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *titleString;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *debtorsArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *dueDate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *notesString;
@end
```

And the debtorsArray is an array of Debtor objects

```
@interface Debtor : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *nameString;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *amountOwedString;
```

How should I go about saving this object since it contains an array. Do I need to create two different Entities, with a relationship between Payment and Debtor? How exactly do I do this, and how would I ensure that they are fetched properly?

Comment: What exactly does debtorsArray contain ? Can they be serialised some how. You could then use transformable type.

Comment: it is an array of Debtor objects, I updated my post with that Debtor Object

Comment: Please see my answer below and please do accept if it works for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create only one entity for `Payment`. You will have to use the '**Transformable**' data type for your attribute `debtorsArray` within this entity.

Then implement the following methods in your `Debtor` class:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder{
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.nameString forKey:@"nameString"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.amountOwnedString forKey:@"amountOwnedString"];
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    if(self = [super init]){
        self.nameString = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"nameString"];
        self.amountOwnedString = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"amountOwnedString"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Entity should be fetched normally like any other fetch query.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there a reason I would use this instead of a to-many relationship?

Comment: That actually depends on your data size I think. I tend to avoid creating multiple nested entities if my data is considerable in size. This way I could be possibly saving a few extra entity calls and fetch requests. I find this way simpler.

Comment: I'll give this a shot, I personally can't confirm it works though yet, I still need to figure out how to save and fetch using Magical Record.

Comment: @Andy Sure! I can confirm that this works as I've used it for exactly the same situation in my project:) but I'll wait for your confirmation. Just asking, what do you exactly mean by a magical record?

Comment: [Magical Record](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord), makes core data simplified.